# Build a door frame

Tags: construction, sound-proofing

We have a back porch about 235 sq ft. the previous owner installed it directly on the 2x4s and purlins. It is extremely noisy.

Will removing metal sheets then laying plywood/OSB and felt and reinstalling metal sheets help with the noise when it rains?

Thought I'd throw in a picture of loud roof.

[image: Back porch]

[image]

Comment: Is the porch open to the world, or is it fully enclosed?

Comment: Probably less costly and more effective (but it certainly won't be "silent") to put sound insulation on the underside of the roof, unless it needs to be torn off and replaced for some other reason.

Comment: Even with 15-17 inches of cellulose loose fill in my attic I hear my metal roof getting rained on. Sound travels through the air, so it has no problem going around the edge of the roof and into the windows. I doubt any roofer would go for it, but laying EDPM rubber membrane roofing on TOP of the steel roof might make a real difference. Or just do that on top of the OSB if you are stripping the steel roof off, which a roofer should be happier with (or you can take a stab at DIY-ing, since it's fairly small, but rubber roofing is tricky to DIY right.)

Comment: apply dynamat to the metal to deaden any reverb it exhibits. might be a bit pricey, i've heard flexseal is a cheaper runner-up in term of effectiveness.

Comment: if you're going to use osb, keep the noise frequency and material mu in mind. For wood that's about 700Hz for 1". Use an app like Spectroid to determine the frequency of your rain noise. If it's 1400Hz, then a half inch will work, 2800Hz=1/4", whereas if it's 350Hz, then you'll need 2" to absorb the wavelength. You'll get hardly any Db attenuation from 1/2 wavelength thickness, and a linear-like reduction from 1/2Mu to 1Mu, where it will be mostly blocked.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to leave a picture, but the short wall and halfway on the long side have polycarbonate clear and tinted panels during the summer. Except for the doorway the rest have panels in the winter. Hopefully will have a door up by next winter.

Comment: Please focus on one question at a time. Deadening the sound of rain on the roof and installing a door in the wall are two totally different questions. Once you have answers, you might work on both at the same time. You may note that you have 2 answers about sound, but none about the door because the door is a totally different question.

Answer (score 6):

Not a huge amount I'm afraid.  It will make *some* difference (the felt will particularly help), but there's no getting away from the fact that metal roofing sheets make an excellent drum.  I would probably do it, because it won't be that expensive (if you do it yourself), but it will still be noisy in the rain.

A pantile or slate roof would be much quieter, but a) that is a lot more expensive; b) it's a *lot* heavier, so you would need new roof timbers too.

Comment: Yes, I suspect the metal resonates with each raindrop.  But—I wonder what would happen if the OP placed some ply over the metal, and some corrugated polycarbonate over that.  It'd still make noise, but maybe less, or maybe of a different quality.

Comment: Yes rain on metal is noisy. I have a small wooden cabin with a plywood roof and asphalt shingles and actually like the sound of the rain on wood. Adding polystyrene insulation (for summer heat) reduced the noise but not that much

Comment: @Huesmann What would be the point of keeping the metal if you added ply and polycarbonate?  Its only function at the moment is the being the waterproof layer, and the polycarbonate would do that.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica: the metal roof could be an appropriate structural support for the polycarbonate (or whatever you put over the metal roof) and adding a layer may be easier than replacing the roof. Of course, the metal roof needs to be strong enough to support the extra layer.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica as I said, the polycarbonate may give a different sound, *potentially* less annoying.  Using ply gives another layer that sound must travel through.  Obviously there will be *some* sound waves that travel around, and not through, the ply.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned "polystyrene insulation", which [has its risks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenfell_Tower_fire) unless you get the right product.  I'd suggest spray-foam rather than sheets, though some suggest [that is not adequate](https://bettersoundproofing.com/does-spray-foam-insulation-reduce-noise/).

I filled-in the underside of my metal bathtub with [ROCKWOOL Safe'n'Sound](https://www.rockwool.com/north-america/products-and-applications/products/safensound/) and it totally worked at deadening the shower noise.

I'm sure if you filled in the stud cavities with ROCKWOOL and if you wanted to tidy up with [decoupling channels](https://hushcitysp.com/uncategorized/what-is-decoupling/) (eg. only) and a finished surface ceiling, it would significantly deaden the pinging sounds.

Comment: I used Rockwool in my bathroom so far it's worked OK to cut some of the noise in the room next to the bathroom